# How do I get the page content from PAMIE?

Tags: python, pamie

I'm using PAMIE to control IE to automatically browse to a list of URLs. I want to find which URLs return IE's malware warning and which ones don't. I'm new to PAMIE, and PAMIE's documentation is non-existent or cryptic at best. How can I get a page's content from PAMIE so I can work with it in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing the CPamie.py file did the trick. Turns out, I didn't even need the page content - PAMIE's findText method lets you match any string on the page. Works great!